# Loop over entire clip with ffmpeg without counting frames

Tags: ffmpeg

Lets say I have a video and I would like to loop it 5 times. It is five seconds long and has framerate 25 FPS (just assume no audio).

I can do

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "loop=4:125,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB" out.mp4
```

However, I needed to calculate that the video is 125 frames long. Is there a way I can loop over a whole video without specifying the number of frames (maybe using some constants)? I would like to use the loop filter, as I use it in more complex setups and calculating the nubmer of frames I need seems like a work that should be done by the computer:-).

The actual command I am running is this, as requested:

```
a1=0 ; a2=2.24 ; b1=1107.12 ; b2=1140.68 ; c1=2.28 ; c2=92.04  \
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 \
       -filter_complex "[0:v]split=3[v0][v1][v2]; \
            [v0]trim=$a1:$a2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v00]; \
            [v1]trim=$c1:$c2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v11]; \
            [v2]trim=$b1:$b2,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v22]; \
            [v00]split=3[va][vb][vc]; \
            [va][v11][vb][v22]concat=n=4[v9]; \
            [v9]loop=7:3195,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[vl]; \
            [vl][vc]concat=n=2[vout0]; \
            [0:a]asplit=3[a0][a1][a2]; \
            [a0]atrim=$a1:$a2,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a00]; \
            [a1]atrim=$c1:$c2,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a11]; \
            [a2]atrim=$b1:$b2,asetpts=PTS-STARTPTS[a22]; \
            [a00]asplit=3[aa][ab][ac]; \
            [aa][a11][ab][a22]concat=n=4:v=0:a=1[a9]; \
            [a9]aloop=7:size=6134400,asetpts=N/SR/TB[al]; \
            [al][ac]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[aout0]"   -map '[vout0]' -map '[aout0]' -c:v libx264  -preset slow -crf 16 -movflags faststart -y 2.mp4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `stream_loop` switch for input to loop that without any calculations:

```
ffmpeg -stream_loop 4 -i input.mp4 output.mp4
```

See [main options](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options)

> **-stream_loop number (input)**
> Set number of times input stream shall be looped. Loop 0 means no loop, loop -1 means infinite loop.

To also answer whether there's any const/var to use in `loop` filter - as of now, it doesn't look like that's possible. [Documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#loop) doesn't list anything, there isn't also anything in the [code](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavfilter/f_loop.c), [size](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavfilter/f_loop.c#L447) is defined as integer higher than or equal to `0`.

Comment: But I cannot use that in filter_complex, can I? Basically what I am trying to do is to cut a part of the video first and then loop that, all in one go.

Comment: You need to be way more accurate in your question then - it didn't mention `filter_complex`, the command you showed is a very simple one that can be replaced with this. Please provide an actual example so that we know what to test the answer with, otherwise you're more or less wanting to get a "how to bake a banana cake" answer while asking "how to peel bananas" - I don't know why this is so common. I'm still not 100% sure what you want to do after your comment (without update to the question BTW) - cutting input is possible with that and no idea why you need it in one go either.

Comment: Well, I thought "I would like to use the loop filter, as I use it in more complex setups" indicated that I use it in `filter_complex`. I expanded the question with the actual code. Looking at it, I could probabl run `split` filter and then `concat` but that does not feel like the correct approach.

As for one go, my impression was that one wants to avoid several reencodings. I wanted to be specific - I am kind of surprised `loop` filter does not support something like what I am requesting, I would assume that "repeat this vide n times" is fairly common usage.

Comment: Not really because there can be hundreds of more or less "advanced" setups and we can't possibly know what you meant with that if you show a completely different command than one that you want to use. Now your question makes much more sense. A thing you could do in Bash, Powershell or any other scripting lang would be to get FPS with `ffprobe`, set number of loops as var, then combine both and multiply them to get size as var. I assume bash looking at the presented code.